# How smart is Hibernate transforming JDBC tuples to Java Objects

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Assume this model,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "play_list")
public class PlayList {
    @Id @Column(name = "code")
    private Long code;
    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinTable(...)
    private List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "song")
public class Song {
    @Id @Column(name = "code")
    private Long code;

    @Lob @Column(name = "raw_data")
    private byte[] rawData; // The binary value of the song (important!)
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "songs")
    private List<PlayList> playLists = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then, if your execute a JPA Query like this one:

```
SELECT pl, s
FROM
    playlist pl
      INNER JOIN pl.songs s
```

Hibernate, executes a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT pl.*, s.*
FROM
    play_list pl
      INNER JOIN play_list_song pls ON pl.code = pls.playlist_code
      INNER JOIN song s ON pls.song_code = s.code
```

I was debugging this code, and Hibernate does bind correctly the JDBC tuples ... let me explain with an example, if you have 2 songs and 2 playlist and both playlist contains the 2 songs, hibernate only maps 4 java objects ...

But, and **this is my question**, in order to create those 4 java objects, **does Hibernate parse and load each JDBC tuple into memory, to later discard duplicated objects** (objects of the same entity and same @Id)??

Why I'm asking this? Well, assume that you execute the previous query and you have a lot of playlists that share songs ... if hibernate loads everything before discarding duplicated objects, then it will read the `byte[] rawData` a lot of times (which it could be a problem if the rawData are in the form of MB magnitude)

Thanks ...

**NOTE:** I'm assuming that Hibernate transform the blob data into a `byte[]` using JDBC `Resultset.getBinaryStream(int)` and that the database (oracle) is returning a `LOB_LOCATOR` in such column ...

Answer (score 0):

> **does Hibernate parse and load each JDBC tuple into memory, to later discard duplicated objects** (objects of the same entity and same @Id)??

You've already traced the query that Hibernate executes.  It must process the results of that query, which do, in your example, contain duplicate playlist data and duplicate song data.  It needs information from every row of the result set, though not every column of every row.

Whether it is possible to cherry-pick the needed data from the result set probably depends more on the database and JDBC driver than on anything else.  If you're concerned about scalability, then you should err on the pessimistic side, assuming that all columns of all rows will be transferred from database to Java.

On the other hand, your concerns about LOB data in particular, though credible, are probably misplaced.  This is something you should *test*, as is all the rest, but I think you'll find that LOB data are transferred from the database only on demand, and that they will be demanded only once per field per distinct entity.